# Binding to Route Events in a View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

If I bind to a router event in the initialize method, the callback is called:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({   
    initialize: function() { 
        router.on("route:test", this.update);
    },

    update: function() {
        console.log('This works');
    }
});
```

But this doesn't work:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "route:test": "update"
    },  

    initialize: function() { },

    update: function() {
        console.log('This never gets called');
    }
});
```

Is there something I am doing wrong in the second case, or am I misunderstanding something?

Is `events` within a view only for DOM-level events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, `events` in a view is only used for DOM events within the element of that view.

> Uses jQuery's delegate function to provide declarative callbacks for DOM events within a view

Documentation is [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents)